# PHP MVC structure and contents

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

i'm new to the Laravel framework and MVC structure, my question is:
 1. should there be any logic in the view section? for example on my homepage

```
@if(empty($data))
<h1>Hello</h1>
{{HTML::link('/login/fb','Login using Facebook')}}
@else
<h1>Hello {{$data->nameDisplay}}</h1>
Image: {{$data->profileUrlImage}}
Email: {{$data->email}}
{{HTML::link('/logout','Logout')}}
@endif

or should that all be done in the controller and just send them that view.
```

2. is there a correct way to organize the views file? i have seen many tutorials on youtube that they have the master layouts inside the layouts foler, the index,profile etc in a folder called sites, the header footer in folder called partials, im just wondering if there is a correct format for organizing the structure or any good tips you can give to help me

thank you :)

Comment: Simple logic like formatting, ifs, loops, etc are generally considered ok for views. To be any efficient you kinda need to. What you want to make sure is that you isolate the scope of the view... So if you don't send a user object to the view the view shouldn't go out on its own and fetch it. That's what they mean with the view being "blind", it doesn't know of any data sources and can only use what's passed to it.